# Subdomains in multisite wordpress do not link to the right place

Tags: virtualhost, wordpress, apache2

I have 2 virtualhosts on my current apache installation, associated to the domains dailymaker.net and dailymaker.com.br; for each one, I have configured a multisite wordpress with 3 subdomains (which are the same for both domains).

The first one I set up was dailymaker.com.br:

— apache configuration —

```
    ServerAdmin deleted email
    DocumentRoot /home/kleber/www/dailymaker_br
    ServerName dailymaker.com.br
    ServerAlias www.dailymaker.com.br
    ServerAlias *.dailymaker.com.br
```

for each subdomain created with wordpress, I have a virtualhost configuration which looks like that:

```
    ServerName space.dailymaker.com.br
    ServerAdmin deleted email
```

The osecond domain I set up was dailymaker.net:

```
    ServerAdmin deleted email
    DocumentRoot /home/kleber/www/dailymaker
    ServerName dailymaker.net
    ServerAlias www.dailymaker.net
    ServerAlias *.dailymaker.com.br
```

for this domain, I also have virtualhost configurations for each subdomain created with wordpress which looks like that:

```
    ServerName space.dailymaker.net
    ServerAlias dailymaker.space
    ServerAlias www.dailymaker.space
    ServerAdmin deleted email
```

The problem I am having now it’s when I try visit either the main page or dashboard for each subdomain from dailymaker.com.br, I am redirect to this url:

```
http://www.dailymaker.net/wp-signup.php?new=space.dailymaker.com.br
```

In the case of dailymaker.net, visiting the main page shows the default index page of apache, but the dashboard is shown normally.

Someone can give a hint of what’s possibly going wrong here?

Comment: Why are you making multiple virtual hosts? WordPress Multisite requires all of the domains to be in the same virtual host.

Comment: it's 2 different websites, in the same server. Each website has its subdomains, which represent diferent areas of the website.

Comment: So they are two completely different WordPress Multisite installations?

Comment: yes, but somehow they are affecting each other, in a way I can't figure out.